# Put an image in the center of a cell with migradoc

Tags: image, pdfsharp, migradoc

I need to put an image in the center of a table's cell.
When I add the image in a cell the image is aligned topleft.
How can I align the image in the center of a cell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
row.Cells[0].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm trying to do a different thing. I'm trying to set the width of the cell according with the size of the image. I'm using 'Column column = table.AddColumn();
 column.Width = Image.FromFile(shotOfImplants).Width;' but I obtain a cell with a differnt size compared with the image "shotOfImplants".

Comment: This only works if your image is in a paragraph, which is in the cell.

Answer (score 30):

You might need to add a paragraph to the cell, set the alignment on the paragraph, and then add the image to the paragraph.

```
row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
row.Cells[0].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
row.Cells[0].AddParagraph().AddImage(imageLocation);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. This should be marked as answer.

Answer (score -1):

In my version of MigraDoc, Jeff and Reuben's solution does not work as shown: Setting the cell's `Format.Alignment` property has no effect, even when the image is inside a paragraph.

However, what *does* work for me is to put the image in a paragraph, just as Jeff and Reuben say, then give the paragraph a *named* style which includes centering.

In my method which predefines all my styles, I do something like:

```
// Here we assume the "TableText" style has already been created

var sty = doc.Styles.AddStyle( "TableTextCenter", "TableText" );
sty.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
```

And at the point where I add the image, I do this:

```
var para = table.Cells[ 0 ].AddParagraph();
para.Style = "TableTextCenter"; // <----- This is the magic!
var img = para.AddImage( imageFileSpec );
img.LockAspectRatio = true;
img.Width = "4cm";
img.WrapFormat = new WrapFormat {
  Style = WrapStyle.Through
};
```

Answer (score -1):

As @Reuben says, what is interesting is:

```
row.Cells[0].AddParagraph().AddImage(imageLocation);
```

I was trying with

```
row.Cells[0].AddImage(imageLocation);
```

And the image was inserted in the document but I couln't get it centered.